# Get a glowing effect when Button pressed

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to achieve an effect something similar to this: http://postimg.org/image/ohalq5r51/ , in Android.

I have tried to make an animation of an image to fade in and out when the button has been pressed. Is there any other way to get the glowing effect or is fade in/out animation the right way to go?

Comment: use '<selector>' for button style....

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#151B8D" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#151B8D" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#151B8D" android:startColor="#151B8D" />

        <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#000000" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Doesn't give a perfect glow but you can edit the code to work like the way you want it